# Filter function

Tags: r, dplyr

For the data:

```
    Id    res
    1     9
    1     8
    1     8
    1     6
    1     5
    1     4
    2     6
    2     6
    2     0
    2     0
    2     0
    2     0
```

I want top four from each group.
When I use

```
dat %>% group_by(Id) %>%
       top_n(4,res)
```

I get

```
Id    res 
1     9 
1     8 
1     8 
1     6 
2     6
2     6 
2     0 
2     0 
2     0 
2     0
```

A filter method is required here. What would be a proper filter logic for this, so that I get only top four rows (ties are allowed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know `top_n` returns more rows if ties.

Maybe this helps?

```
dat %>% group_by(Id) %>% arrange(desc(res)) %>% filter(row_number()<=4)

  Id res
1  1   9
2  1   8
3  1   8
4  1   6
5  2   6
6  2   6
7  2   0
8  2   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use `head`, here with `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, head(res,4), Id]
```

Or as per @Jack Wheeler rightly underlined:

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[1:4], by = Id]
```

Comment: You could also do this using .SD which is part of data.table `setDT(df)[, .SD[1:4], by = Id]`

Comment: It mainly depends if there are more columns or not in the data as `.SD` is not very efficient.

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes, this is exactly like what you came up with earlier today; I also thought of throwing out your other(faster) idea in this context or `indx <- df[, .I[1:4], by = Id]$V1 ;df[indx]`. I've been playing around benchmarking both options throughout the day to get a better understanding of when to use each

Comment: I think you'd need `order(-res)` as in: `setDT(df)[order(-res), head(.SD, 4L), by=Id]`. Also, `head()` and `[]` do things differently when number of observations in group are less than 4.